# Cannot Compile Hash Table ADT - C

Tags: c, hash

I keep getting the error:

1. assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

when trying to compile my Hash table ADT using the command:

```
gcc hash_NEW.c -c
```

the error is encountered in 1 function the larger .c file.
Thanks for the help in advance

Error 1 occurs here at line (index = table->hash_func;)

```
void insert_hash(Phash_table table, char *key, void *data){
    Phash_entry new;   //pointer to a new node of type hash_entry
    int index;

    new = (Phash_entry)malloc(sizeof(hash_entry));
    new->key = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(key));  //creates the key array based on the length of the string-based key
    new->data = data;              //stores the user's data into the node
    strcpy(new->key,key);          //copies the key into the node

                                   //calling the hash function in the user's program
    index = table->hash_func;      //index will hold the hash table value for where the new 
    table->buckets[index] = new;   //Assigns the pointer at the index value to the new node
    table->total++;                //increment the total (total # of buckets)
}
```

Portion of HEADER FILE:

```
typedef struct hash_table_ {
    hash_entry **buckets;           //Pointer to a pointer to a Linked List of type hash_entry
    int (*hash_func)(char *);
    int (*cmp_func)(void *, void *);
    int size;
    void **sorted_array;      //Array used to sort each hash entry
    int index;//=0
    int total; //=0
    int sort_num; //=0  
} hash_table, *Phash_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the type definition, you can see that `Phash_table` is a pointer to a structure whose field `hash_func` is a function that takes a `char *` and returns an `int`.

Most probably you want:

```
 index = table->hash_func(key);
```

as it stands you are trying to assign a "pointer to a function" to an "int" which is very unlikey to be what you need.

Comment: yeah I figured out the second one right after I posted it ha. I added the portion of the header file that correlates to that struct. I believe the code you provided is indeed the correction. That way i call the user's hash function with the argument of key. therefore getting back the correct index value. Ah makes sense! thanks for the quick response!!

Comment: Yup now it compiles! Awesome I cant thank you enough, I needed fresh eyes to look at this

Comment: yw. Just watch out the line `strcpy(new->key,key);`. You're going to have troubles.

Comment: Why do you say that? It should take the key value given by the user and insert it into that portion of the node(which is malloced to the correct size). How will this give me problems I am curious now

Comment: You allocated `strlen(key)` bytes for `new->key` but you need at leaset `strlen(key)+1` bytes to account for the `'\0'` at the end. I used to remember this by noticing that you need 1 byte to store an empty (0-length) string. Funny is that this error can go unnoticed for long time because malloc will most probably round the size to the next multiple of 4 (if not 8) and for most keys it will work fine. One day, though, you'll get a key that fits exactly in the allocated block and `strcpy` will write on someone else memory.Again, you may be lucky and nothing happens. Or you can get a segfault.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes perfect sense. For some reason I was thinking strlen included the \0 and not just the characters up to it. I see what you mean about overwriting other memory, since its not allocated for the correct amount of spaces. Thanks for the heads up I will have to fix that.